# Quickly list random set of files in directory in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

**Question:**
I am looking for a performant, concise way to list *N* randomly selected files in a Linux directory using only Bash. The files must be randomly selected from different subdirectories.

**Why I'm asking:**
In Linux, I often want to test a random selection of files in a directory for some property. The directories contain 1000's of files, so I only want to test a small number of them, but I want to take them from different subdirectories in the directory of interest.

The following returns the paths of 50 "randomly"-selected files:

`find /dir/of/interest/ -type f | sort -R | head -n 50`

The directory contains many files, and resides on a mounted file system with slow read times (accessed through ssh), so the command can take many minutes. I believe the issue is that the first `find` command finds every file (slow), and only then prints a random selection.

Comment: Can you afford a slow run every `n` executions of the script? IF yes you can cache the output of find and reuse that instead of rerunning the command.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution that will work 'on the fly', without the need to cache the output of find (would need to do this for ~12 TB, ~1e7 files).

Comment: Yes, like you wrote your command, find will find ALL of your 1000's files, and then the result is processed by piped command. I don't know find options allowing to limit output, so your issue seems not solvable. Don't you have issue way to improve the read efficiencies of the mounted file system?

Comment: I was originally reading your requirement of "using only bash" as prohibiting external calls, which would require using `$RANDOM` and bash arrays (and would definitely not be very fast). You're not going to get any faster than `find` without `locate` or some other cached result.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `locate` and `updatedb` updates regularly (daily is probably the default), you could:

```
$ locate /home/james/test | sort -R | head -5
/home/james/test/10kfiles/out_708.txt
/home/james/test/10kfiles/out_9637.txt
/home/james/test/compr/bar
/home/james/test/10kfiles/out_3788.txt
/home/james/test/test
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this would work well, but I don't have this installed on the servers I'm accessing. I'm hoping to find a way that doesn't require building a database, but perhaps this is fundamentally impossible.

Answer (score 2):

How often do you need it? Do the work periodically in advance to have it quickly available when you need it.

Create a `refreshList` script.

```
#! /bin/env bash

find /dir/of/interest/ -type f | sort -R | head -n 50 >/tmp/rand.list
mv -f /tmp/rand.list ~
```

Put it in your crontab.

```
0 7-20 * * 1-5 nice -25 ~/refresh
```

Then you will always have a ~/rand.list that's under an hour old.

If you don't want to use `cron` and aren't too picky about how old it is, just write a function that refreshes the file *after* you use it every time.

```
randFiles() {
  cat ~/rand.list
  {  find /dir/of/interest/ -type f |
       sort -R | head -n 50 >/tmp/rand.list
      mv -f /tmp/rand.list ~
  } &
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run locate and the find command is too slow, is there any reason this has to be done in real time?

Would it be possible to use cron to dump the output of the find command into a file and then do the random pick out of there?

Comment: This was my thought.

Comment: I would like to be able to do it in real time, as I often need to do this immediately after renaming all the files in the directory.

Comment: The solutions aren't mutually exclusive. You can use sed with the -i switch to update your file as they are renamed. Alternatively (and more efficiently), just update the entries for that directory just before starting the actual process.